# How to create autocomplete combobox in PyQt4?

Tags: python, combobox, autocomplete, pyqt4, qcombobox

How to create autocomplete combobox in PyQt4?

Example what I want:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: What's the issue? An editable ``QComboBox`` should have autocomplete by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the same behaviour as in the example, you will need to change the [completion mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#completionMode-prop) of the [completer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#completer) for the combobox.

By default, the completion mode is inline (i.e. just selected text, with no alternatives). To get the drop-down list of possible alternatives, do:

```
    combobox.completer().setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post. Is there a way to also add the ability for this to allow you to select MULTIPLE choices?

Comment: @RyanGlenn Please ask a  new question, since your request seems totally unrelated to the original question (and I'm not even sure what you mean).

Answer (score 5):

`combobox.setEditable(True) combobox.completer().setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.PopupCompletion) combobox.setInsertPolicy(QComboBox.NoInsert)`

First line : autocompletion is only available for an editable combobox.

Second line : sets required behavior for autocomplete method

Last line : prevents the user to add items to the list (to better match the example behavior you provided)